# Creating a foriegn key in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to be able to create a foreign key there is something wrong in the syntax probably. Given below are the tables :-

```
CREATE TABLE ADMINMEMBER
(
  ADMIN_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADMIN_NAME VARCHAR(300) ,
  ADMIN_JOB VARCHAR(300) 
);

CREATE TABLE TRAINER
( TRAINER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, TRAINER_NAME VARCHAR(300)
, TRAINER_SPECIALITY VARCHAR(300)
, TRAINER_JOINDATE DATE
, ADMIN_ID int constraint FKF REFERENCES ADMINMEMBER(ADMIN_ID)
);
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong or how would i successfully create a foreign key?

Comment: that's not the correct syntax to do that - have you tried looking up the [MySQL Documentation?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is worng.

Change the second table create statemenr to:

```
CREATE TABLE TRAINER
( TRAINER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, TRAINER_NAME VARCHAR(300)
, TRAINER_SPECIALITY VARCHAR(300)
, TRAINER_JOINDATE DATE
, ADMIN_ID int
, FOREIGN KEY  (ADMIN_ID)  REFERENCES ADMINMEMBER(ADMIN_ID)
);
```